# Eclipse type proposal change from 3.4 to 3.5 - configurable?

Tags: java, eclipse

If I already have the types imported, in Eclipse 3.4, I get concrete default classes, but in 3.5 I just get the interface for `java.util.Collections`. For example, hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> here:

`Map map = new` <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>

On 3.4, i get offered `HashMap()`, on 3.5 `Map()` (which then gets defaulted to a new impl with methods templated).

For `List`, on 3.4 I'm offered `ArrayList()` but on 3.5 `List()` only.

Is this configurable in the templates or similar?

Comment: Good to see I'm not the only one who thinks the JDT content assist in Eclipse 3.5 is a step back from Eclipse 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it is configurable, but I know that if you have one Map instanciated as an `HashMap`, the second one will come with an `HashMap` present in the "Content assist" list.

`Map<Integer, String> m = new HashMap<Integer, String>();`
`Map<Integer, String> m2  =`<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> => `HashMap`

See all the  [eclipse Galileo 3.5 JDT Tips and Tricks](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html?view=co)

Answer (score 2):

I have just faced the same problem. The solution is Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced
Make sure you have "Java Proposals" selected. Once you enable this you should have the type proposal on ctrl + space.