# Implemented classes / subclasses in content assist in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, subclass, eclipse-jdt, content-assist

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
List<String> list = new
```

and then hit Ctrl+Space and get `ArrayList<String>()` (among others) to show up in the type proposal.

I thought I had this working previously, but I recently had to reinstall and can't find the setting for it.

This is Eclipse Java EE helios, but I can upgrade to indigo if need be.

I tried looking [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html) for help, but didn't find the info I was looking for.  I've tried checking all of the boxes under "Default Proposal Kinds" (Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced" to no avail.

Comment: Really?  That used to work?  I've never seen that.  I'm interested to see how it's done.

Comment: That is the standard behavior in IntelliJ

Comment: That does not appear possible even in the link you forwarded.  I have never seen that behavior.  Are you sure it was working before?

Comment: And it is standard Netbeans behavior. Why so popular IDE like Eclipse doesn't have so useful feature. Without this I have to deep in to API that sometimes is unknown.

Comment: Is this the same problem? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1582969/1061499

Comment: Did you make sure that you imported java.util.List first.

Comment: Using 3.5, Eclipse IDE for Java Developers: If I import `java.util.List` first (e.g. by using ctrl+space on `List`), it gives me the suggestions `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` (and some more) when I hit space after `List<String> list = new `. With Indigo the same thing does not work. A fix is given for the question posted above, but it seems still dependent on 'popular' choices (e.g. it gave me the `LinkedList` only after I had selected it once myself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't know which class implement the interface, and will not load them for all interfaces it has. BUT, **Eclipse can learn** what you use and show it to you on next use, maybe that's what happened to you, with time you taught Eclipse the implemented classes!

Here's an example of Eclipse before learning/and after learning what classes implement `Map`.

[image]

As you can see in the image, the first time, Eclipse didn't know anything other than `HashMap`, which I used before.

After that, I used `TreeMap` and `LinkedHashMap` by typing them manually (first time only) and Eclipse now cached them.

As the guys suggested, you can put the point on `Map` and click `Ctrl+T` it will give all the classes the implements this. Will be helpful the first time.

**UPDATE in 2014!**

As @K.Carpenter noticed, this feature is disabled in newer Eclipse versions. To re-enable it. Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced.

Under *Default Proposal Kinds*, you will need to check *Java Type Proposals*

Comment: In fact this is the best answer but not exacly what I expected.

Comment: Ohhh, ok.  That explains why it has only given me ArrayList for list, and HashMap for Map.

Comment: It's a couple years later now, but have any versions of Eclipse since Galileo supported this learning feature? I definitely have not seen this happen since then.

Comment: @K.Carpenter you are right. It became a configuration and it's disabled by default. I'm updating the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Code like this is one of my pet hates of Java Generics. I use Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) libraries to make my generics code more readable, and as a side-effect don't need this particular feature in Eclipse (though I agree it should be implemented). Guava has similar support for Sets too.

For example, I would normally declare my code as follows:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
...
List myList<String> = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see Eclipse doing this, but I guess that the content assist never worked without a start character (unless there is some hidden feature we don't know).

Well, having this in mind, what I do to workaround from *'getting locked with the most used implementations'* is to look at the javadoc in the `All Known Implementing Classes` section, to see other possibilities that I could use.

- [List Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
- [Complete Java 7 Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

I know it is not an in-Eclipse solution, but it may help some users that got stuck in the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretend to be an answer to your question but I use Quick Fix (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) to define a new local variable or field.

First, I type (maybe using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for Content Assist):

```
new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> which assigns statement to new local variable by generating variable definition with type being instantiated:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Finally, I use tab (one may also use Enter) to navigate between inserted `arrayList` and `ArrayList` to specify the exact variable name and its type from drop-down list:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Pressing tab for third time moves cursor to the end of statement.

Hope, you'll find this way useful too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that you can add a new template to eclipse, then all you have to do is type arraylist, press ctrl + space and it creates the entire declaration for you. All you have to do is add the type and name.

**[Save this file, then import it to eclipse](http://www.box.com/shared/pi88fh7gih)**

Here’s how to import/export a template

- Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates
- Select the templates you want. NB! The checkboxes don’t indicate
  what’s selected; they are used to enable/disable a template. A
  template is selected if the whole row in the table is selected, so
  use Ctrl+Left Click or method specific to your OS to multi-select
  templates.
- Click Import… and choose the XML file you received. Or Export… and
  provide a filename.

Type arrayList


[image: Type arraylist]

**Press ctrl+space and choose arraylist**

[image: Press Ctrl + Space]

**Fill in the type and name**
[image: Fill in the type and name]

Answer (score 0):

I am able to do this but it doesn't show up in the type proposal. Try typing:

`List<String> list = new Ar`

Hit Ctrl-Space and just accept the first suggestion. It completes to `ArrayList<String>()` for me (this is using the SpringSource Tool Suite Eclipse distribution).

Comment: I can do that, but I don't want to be locked into ArrayList.  I want all of the possible ones.  I don't want to have to know what the implemented class begins with.  Thanks.